# a non halachic pirush on maseches kelim

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, mishna, chasidut-hasidism, commentaries, maseches-keilim

I recall once having seen a pirush on maseches kelim from a kabalah - chasidus viewpoint, and i since cant recall the name of the sefer or who wrote it, any ideas?